# URL rewrites or redirections in AWS Elastic Beanstalk (with Spring Boot application)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot application hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstack.

In the application properties I have:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/PartToRemove
```

so all my URL are:

```
https://example.com/PartToRemove/path/to/the/particlar/endpoint
```

Now I would like to remove the `PartToRemove` to have:

```
https://example.com/path/to/the/particlar/endpoint
```

At the Spring Boot level it is easy - I just need to remove line

```
server.servlet.context-path=/PartToRemove
```

from my configuration.

**BUT**

... I would like to keep "backward compatibility" for all users who know the old URLs only. So I was thinking about setting some rewrite or redirection from the old `https://example.com/PartToRemove/path/to/the/particlar/endpoint` to the new `https://example.com/path/to/the/particlar/endpoint` URLs.

I'm not very familiar with AWS so I'm not sure where to do this. I was thinking about something like mod_rewrite in .htaccess file but I have no idea if it is a proper way.

I'm deploying the application as a zip file so I can use `.ebextensions` if it would help.

Any ideas on how to achieve such redirection or rewrite?

Comment: In the following link they are redirecting http to https but you can also add a rewrite rule. https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

Comment: @kimy82 thanks. I saw this. But she, in this video doing the configuration change directly on EC2 connected to ELB with my application. But each deployment of a new version of application causes replacing the old EC2 instance with a new one. How to persist such configuration? I do not want to reconfigure the new EC2 instance after each deployment...

Comment: True, I can't see how to place a rewrite at load balancer level. Maybe a good option is add your old context path in the controller itself like this _@RequestMapping({ "/PartToRemove/...", "/..." })_ so you can have the new and the old path working and remove the server.servlet.context-path property.

Comment: @kimy82 I have around 500 endpoints... I do not want to do the same duplication for every single endpoint.

Comment: Yeah, I do know it is not a good solution :-( It is the only one I came up with

Comment: It looks like you can maybe achieve that with the "Application Load Balancer" instead of the classic one. https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/